# The form of the characteristic polynomial of matrices with eigenvalues 0 and 1

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial

I have been working on homework for a CS course and it is rife with linear algebra.
On one of the questions, I came to brood about the following conundrum (not really):

If a matrix has only eigenvalues of 1 and 0, is it always the case that the characteristic polynomial will be of the form $p(x)=(1-x)^kx^l$, $s.t.:k,l\in \mathbb R$?

Comment: If those are the only eigenvalues, then what other factors _could_ the characteristic polynomial have?

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvalues of a matrix are the roots of the characteristic polynomial $p(x)$. If the only eigenvalues of the matrix are 0 and 1, the fundamental theorem of algebra tells us $p(x)=a(x-1)^kx^l$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $k,l\in\mathbb{N}$. But the characteristic polynomial is always monic, so we must have $a=1$.